# How to get the taxonomy terms related to a content type in drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am using `field_info_instances()` to get the list of a content type's cck fields

```
$my_fields = field_info_instances("node", "my_custom_content_type");
```

What I want is to get the taxonomy terms related to the content type. How to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this information using the Drupal API for taxonomy:

```
taxonomy_get_vocabularies($type = 'my_custom_content_type');
```